# How to package JRE with application in windows for target UNIX machine

Tags: java, windows, unix, packaging

I have developed a simple Java App in windows which I now want to distribute for LINUX/UNIX machine. How should I package the JRE with my application so that it could be run on target UNIX machine with no JRE or JDK installed ?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. I have done lot of researched but not getting it quite right

Answer (score 0):

Package your application with Docker(https://www.docker.com/), using the Java DockerFile (http://dockerfile.github.io/#/java)?

Comment: Thanks JP Moresmau. Docker is really good. I am done writing a dockerfile. I have a requirement now to copy the files from docker host(boot2docker file system) to the image I am trying to build. How can I do it using dockerfile. Please advise.

Comment: Heres my dockerfile to run simple HelloWorld in Java in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

```
############################################################
# Dockerfile to run a Java based Application
# Based on an Ubuntu Image
############################################################

#Set the base image to use to Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:14.04


# Set the file maintainer (your name - the file's author)
MAINTAINER NB

# Set env variables used in this Dockerfile (add a unique prefix, such as    DOCKYARD)
# Local directory with project source
#TO DO

# Install JDK and JRE
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-        set-selections
RUN apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y
RUN apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default


# Copy entrypoint script into the image
WORKDIR $DOCKYARD_SRC
COPY ./run.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

Comment: $DOCKYARD_SRC is the directory where I want to have Hello World Java code and shell script to compile and  run the HelloWorld.java